# How can I detect if the exe name has changed since the process was started

Tags: delphi, winapi

We have a Delphi Application which is automatically updated, when we update the program we change the current exe name and place its updated version in the same folder. this has some great benefits and ensures when the program is next run, the updated version will be called.

Having said this, it would be great if I could also call to check that the process running is linked to the exe with the correct name, or if an update has happened.

Does anyone know how to identify this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to me that if you know you're updating the executable, then you know it's been updated. If it's an out-of-process thing, then your best option is to periodically check the version number (i.e. every hour), and notify them with a notification area icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to set up change notification object using FindFirstChangeNotification API (see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28VS.85%29.aspx)) with FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME filter. Then when you receive notification, check is it about your exe and take appropriate action.
There is components available which wrap this API, ie if you have [JVCL](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/) installed then I'm pretty sure it has one.

Answer (score 0):

If the process is running, you can't rename its executable file AFAIK. So I don't get the point of your question.

To check for a running exe version, use the GetVersion API and retrieve its version number.

Comment: You can rename a file if you've set the `IMAGE_FILE_NET_RUN_FROM_SWAP` PE image flag. Bizarrly you're also allowed to rename a running executable, but not delete it.

Comment: as Ian says you can rename, as that is the whole principle of our update cycle, and it works like a dream.

Comment: @all You're right: I didn't test it, because it just sounded too strange to me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetCurrentProcessId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a PID which you pass to [OpenProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can then get the fully qualified path for the location with [GetModuleFileNameEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I suppose you have some sort of file hierarchy/naming convention which you could use to determine whether the current exe is the latest one. [PathStripPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) might be handy or some of the other [path functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I don't necessarily see that this will help, but GetCurrentProcessId, OpenProcess and finally GetModuleFileNameEx is overkill to get module file name. Just call GetModuleFileName and pass NULL as the HMODULE.

Comment: Duhhh moment : ) You're right. I'm too used to using that function on modules belonging to other processes.

Comment: I'm not sure that the GetModuleFileName and other "process info routines" will work in this case - I'd expect them to return the original filename, not the updated one. But I haven't tested it...

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for Delphi would be be to use ParamStr(0) - which has the full path and filename of the exe. Store the exe file's DateTimeStamp at program start. Then periodically check if it has changed...